# RxJS Observable: Emit when specific part of the object changes

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I have a complex object having child objects and arrays and so on.

I can easily create a Subject/BehaviourSubject or Observable from this object so that I can "next" (emit) the new state to the subscribers.

[ex: `let appEnv$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject<IWebSocketAppEnv>(appEnv);`]

However I don't want all my subscribers to be notified every time the object changes. For instance for one of my subscriber, I only want to be notified when a change occurs on an elements of an array of that object.

Actually what I want is something redux is already doing. In redux, I can subscribe to the store but selecting only a child element.

I want to implement the same infrastructure for my back-end websocket server application.

How can I achieve that with RxJS?

Comment: I take it you don't want to use Redux in your application?

Comment: Yes, hopefully. I already run redux on client side (Angular) and on server side I simply prefer to have some Rxjs subjects to handle that, if possible.

Comment: Something like the ngrx [`select`](https://github.com/ngrx/core/blob/v1.2.0/src/operator/select.ts) operator sounds suited to your use case.

Comment: I dont have ngrx, which is on client side. I am on serverside (nodejs)

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use **distinctUntilChanged** operator. [(docs)](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinctUntilChanged)

Let's assume that the object's structure is:

```
{
  articleId: 0,
  comments: [ 'lorem', 'ipsum' ]
}
```

We want to be as cool as firebase guys so we'll update comments in real-time when the updated object has a different array.

I'm using `RxJS5` for observables and `lodash` to compare arrays because operator's default behavior won't compare them in the way we want them to be compared.

```
// Our BehaviorSubject which emits new object.
// For those who don't know: it'll emit the latest emitted value when subscribing to it.
const object$ = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({
  articleId: 0,
  comments: [],
}); 

// If you want specific parts of your application 
// to react only when a specific part of the object has changed, you 
// have to create another observable using 'map' and 
// 'distinctUntilChanged' operator and subscribe to it.
const comments$ = object$
  .map(object => object.comments) // we want to emit comments only
  .distinctUntilChanged((a, b) => _.isEqual(a, b)); // emit only when currently emitted value is different than previous one.

comments$.subscribe(v => console.log(v)); // log fresh comments

object$.next({
  articleId: 1,
  comments: [],
});

object$.next({
  articleId: 1,
  comments: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
});

object$.next({
  articleId: 2,
  comments: ['lorem', 'ipsum'],
});

object$.next({
  articleId: 2,
  comments: ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet'],
});
```

effect:

```
[]
["lorem", "ipsum"]
["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

effect without `distinctUntilChanged` operator:

```
[]
[]
["lorem", "ipsum"]
["lorem", "ipsum"]
["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet"]
```

[***JSFiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/MichalCafe/rkgkewpt/1/)

Comment: I think _.isEqual(a, b) should be !_.isEqual(a, b), am I right?

Comment: According to docs, it has to return false to emit a new value. `_.isEqual(a, b)` is a valid comparison in this case.

Comment: This is a brilliant and underrated solution, Thanks @MichałPietraszko

Answer (score -2):

we can resolve it by partial subscription to the source observable (complex object in your case) based on a condition.

Rxjs [takeWhile](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile) helps to do that.
Subscription can be made only when a certain condition is satisfied and then process the emitted output.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takewhile.html

Comment: `takeWhile` will complete your stream so it is not really usable to track all changes over time of a sub-tree of the original $env object